# Multiple RTSP Streaming not working

Tags: android

I had used 4 VideoView in my Activity.If uri1 is available and other uri's are not available means all video view shows uri1's video.
If other uri's are available but uri1 is not up means all videoview's are not showing anything. Guide me to solve this issue.

```
String uri1="rtsp://admin:admin@Serverurl1"
String uri2="rtsp://admin:admin@Serverurl2"
String uri3="rtsp://admin:admin@Serverurl3"
String uri4="rtsp://admin:admin@Serverurl4"

videoview1.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(uri1));
videoview2.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(uri2));
videoview3.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(uri3));
videoview4.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(uri4));
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can see my answer below

Comment: I had applied that, but there is no effect :( .FYI it doesn't comes to Catch block...

Comment: there is not any exception? and it is working on my env. which sdk did you use? give more details please

Comment: You are checking with RTSP Stream or Local File URL ? This will work for Local File URL. But It is not working for RTSP Streaming.. :( . I am using sdk version 4.1.1

Comment: I try from url, your rtsp url is fine ?

Comment: yes, My url is fine. I had checked that with VLC also..

Comment: From which URL you are tried ? RTSP or HTTP ? My Problem is only on RTSP. It's perfectly working for HTTP and Local file URL ... :( . If you have the suggestion tell me @Ersin Gülbahar

Comment: I use RTSP url on my env

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
vv1=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.vv1);
vv2=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.vv2);
vv3=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.vv3);
vv4=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.vv4);


try {
vv1.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(url1)); 
vv1.requestFocus();
vv1.start();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
}
try {
vv2.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(url2)); 
vv2.requestFocus();
vv2.start();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
}
try {
vv3.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(url3)); 
vv3.requestFocus();
vv3.start();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
}
try {
vv4.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(url4)); 
vv4.requestFocus();
vv4.start();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
}
```